# Direct-Admin Control Panel: How do I move additional domain to user of reseller?

Tags: domains

In direct-admin control panel I create a reseller.

Converting my old cpanel server backup to direct-admin and transfer to my new direct-admin panel.

But in restore full backup in direct admin server create a user and all domains add for that user as additional domain not normal user.

For example I have a reseller user name ***maindomain*** and another user ***transuser***.

Now all of domains are additional domain of *transuser* and when I login with *transuser* display domain administrator.

How can I move these domains to maindomain reseller?

And show users and domains separate in normal user creating under resellers?

Note: I have dedicate server and ssh access and direct-admin, admin level.

Image at my users list:

[image]

Comment: Hi, MinA. It's not very clear what you're asking. It is clear that English is not your first language :) Can you try to clarify your question? Perhaps find someone to help you translate more effectively?

Comment: @Thomas i add image of my users list is that enough?

Comment: From what I can gather, you're asking about how to perform a function in a specific software application. I've edited the title of your question to clarify this (my edit needs approved), in case someone here has used that application. However, you're probably better off asking Direct-Admin's customer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in the [direct-admin forum](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=58):

> Transfer a domain from one user to another

There is a new script in testing for this. Sample usage:

> cd /usr/local/directadmin/scripts
>
> ./move_domain.sh domain.com olduser newuser

If the `newuser` does not exist yet, then create `newuser` with `fakedomain.com`, transfer the domain, then delete `fakedomain.com`.

Note, that if you have any apache owned files, they'll be `chown`-ed to the new user. Also, if you have `apache_public_html=1` in your directadmin.conf, I would recommended to change it to `apache_public_html=0` and use the secure access group method instead.

### Older (outdated) method:

1) Go to Reseller Panel -> Manage User Backups and make a backup of the user who owns the domain you want to transfer.

2) Login as that user, go to User Panel -> Domain Administration -> Change domain name, and change the name of that domain to something different (ie: from domain.com to domain2.com).  This is done so that you can restore the domain on the other account without DA complaining that it already exists.

3) Go back into the Reseller Panel, and create the a new user.  Set the domain to the actual name of the domain you want transferred.  If the user already exists, then just create the domain through the User Panel -> Domain Administration menu.

4) Take the backup from step 1, and rename is from olduser.tar.gz to newuser.tar.gz, where newuser is the name you are transferring TO and olduser is the name you are transferring FROM.

5) From Reseller Panel -> Manage User Backups, select newuser.tar.gz and restore it into the newuser account.  This should set all the data from the domain into the new user.

6) Once you've verified that everything is correct and as it should be, log back into the olduser account and delete domain2.com.

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".
Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.  But you went to a lot of effort to come back and write up an answer, so I'll upvote that!

Comment: @MadHatter thank mad but i know that , i say i give -3 vote for my question and i dont know that reason

Comment: I told you above: either it doesn't show enough research effort, or it is unclear, or it is not useful.  Those are the standard reasons for a downvote-without-comment.

Comment: but i ask question that is useful for me and i describe everything i can say

Comment: Everyone's question is useful for them, that's why they ask it.  The issue is how useful it is for others; in this case, not much, because the answer is specific to a single provider.  This is probably not the right place for this discussion; with my upvote, you have enough privilege to access http://meta.serverfault.com/, and you can ask this question there if you want a better answer, from more people than just me.